# getting error while importing a site to a sitecollection sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, migration, site-collection, site-template, site

I exported a site which have many sub sites, and then that sub sites have several sub sites, but getting following error if someone got any idea about it.

> [16/07/2012 10:00:20]: Start Time: 16/07/2012 10:00:20.
>   [16/07/2012 10:00:20]: Progress: Initializing Import.
>   [16/07/2012 10:00:30]: FatalError: Could not find WebTemplate #10016 with LCID 1033.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.VerifyWebTemplate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.Validate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.DeserializeAndValidate()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.VerifyRequirements()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
>   [16/07/2012 10:00:32]: Progress: Import Completed.
>   [16/07/2012 10:00:32]: Finish Time: 16/07/2012 10:00:32.
>   [16/07/2012 10:00:32]: Completed with 0 warnings.
>   [16/07/2012 10:00:32]: Completed with 1 errors.

I tried using this software

[spdeploymentwizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/)

I also tried STSADM for importing/exporting but gave me same error

I tried to import it to another site collection and same site collection as well but nothing changed.

I also looked at backing up but its a site not web/site collection and so I cant backup site having subsites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming your structure looks somewhat like this

*Site Collection 1* > Site A > number of subsites(n)

*Site Collection 2* > [**restore Site A > with all subsites (n)*]

You are looking to restore Site A on a different *site collection* 2 with all its subsites intact.

Just ensure you do not create any existing subsite named siteA. Template issue generally occurs in that case. Incase you have used a custom template like the ones from fab 40 , you may need to ensure they exist in the *site collection 2* before the import is initiated.

Comment: I added all of available templates to site collection 2 but it still gave me same error, however I tried importing site to the same sitecollection but to the root and still got same error :(

Comment: Do not restore it to the root. You are essentially exporting a subsite that has a lot of subsite within itself. Import it as a subsite and not on the root of the target site collection. 

Export : stsadm -o export -url http://sitecol1/siteA        -filename siteA.cab

Import : stsadm -o import -url http://sitecol2/siteA        -filename siteA.cab

Comment: So do i have to create a site in site collection 2 before importing, with the same name as of the site i exported ? cheers

Comment: No. You do need to create a site with the same name. Just create a site collection 2 and have no subsites in it before the import. Then run the import command as mentioned above, and SharePoint will create the subsite with same name "Site A" for you while taking care of the templates.

Comment: still getting same error, going to try on a different VPC now

Comment: there is some problem with VPC, I tried it on another VPC it did worked up till a point i got another exception and I will ask another question for that however this template is still a mystery i guess

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41049/getting-error-while-importing-a-site