# getting error while importing a site

Tags: 2007, migration, site-collection, site

I exported a site which have many sub sites, and then that sub sites have several sub sites, but getting following error if someone got any idea about it.

> > [16/07/2012 13:47:20]: FatalError: Non-supported field type change.
>
> The field cannot be changed to the new type. Please check the new type
>   and try again.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateField(String bstrUrl,
>   String
>
> > bstrListName, String bstrXML)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.set_SchemaXml(String value)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.CreateOrUpdateField(SPList
> >     list, String fieldName, XmlNode fieldNode)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.UpdateListFields(SPList
> >     list, Dictionary`2 listMetaData)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListSerializer.SetObjectData(Object
> >     obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
> >     ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type
> >     objectType, Boolean isChildObject)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type
> >     objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
> >     serializationStream)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream
> >     serializationStream)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportObjectManager.ProcessObject(XmlReader
> >     xmlReader)    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()    at
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run() [16/07/2012 13:49:28]:
> >     Progress: Import Completed. [16/07/2012 13:49:28]: Finish Time:
> >     16/07/2012 13:49:28. [16/07/2012 13:49:28]: Completed with 0 warnings.
> >     [16/07/2012 13:49:28]: Completed with 1 errors.

tried on a different VPC manage to get another exception

> FatalError: The folder that would hold URL '/s/a/aasdasd' does not exist on the server.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateWeb(String bstrUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String bstrWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueWeb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid& pgWebId, Guid& pgRootFolderId, Boolean bCreateSystemCatalogs)

I tried using this software

[spdeploymentwizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/)

I also tried STSADM for importing/exporting but gave me same error

I tried to import it to another site collection and same site collection as well but nothing changed.

I also looked at backing up but its a site not web/site collection and so I cant backup site having subsites.

**Is there any way I can move this site without encountering these errors or the validations its doing :/ as right now am testing it on dev environment it got loads of bugs which i cant fix i guess but live server will be alright, suggest alternatives to this method as well if yu can**

Comment: You may get this exception when the restore is trying to create a list column with a name which is already used for any existing site column in the target site collection and these two have different data type.

Comment: Additionally, did you deploy any custom feature on the actual site collection which is not activated in the target site collection where the subsites are being imported.

Comment: I just created a new site collection and its all empty, so dont think if there is any existing site column there until its sharepoint default site column

Comment: getting another exception now so i edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issues with custom webparts and site definitions when they were deployed so there wasn't much I could do about it, so didn't migrated this site collection however created new site collection from scratch.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)